Is internet with 1gbps enough to run a node?
So as the title suggests, will 1gbps be enough or will my node lag? Given that hardware is not a bottleneck.


Internet service should be at least 1GBbit/s symmetric, commercial. 10GBit/s preferred.

As per the docs, 1gbps is possible when running a validator but 10 is preferable

Thanks, I thought those docs were a bit outdated, does that minimum 1gbps still holds?
